Logarithm of the arithmetic-geometric sum expression - find the expression of logarithm of the numerator
Sorry for the lack of context, but essentially, I want to evaluate the logarithm of $S_n$ , where:
$$\displaystyle{S_n = \frac{ab - (a + nd)br^n}{1-r}} + \frac{dbr(1-r^n)}{(1-r)^2}$$
I decided to continue as follows:
$$
S_n = \frac{(ab - (a + nd)br^n)(1-r) + dbr(1-r^n)}{(1-r)^2}\\
$$
Now since $S_n$ is the fraction, $\ln S_n = \ln (\text{numerator}) - \ln (\text{denominator})$ where $\ln (\text{denominator}) = \ln((1 - r)^2) = 2\ln(1 - r)$, so now we focus on the numerator: $(ab - (a + nd)br^n)(1-r) + dbr(1-r^n)$
So I decided to try to expand and factor the numerator expression
$$
\begin{gather}
(ab - (a + nd)br^n)(1-r) + dbr(1-r^n) \\
= ab - (a + nd)br^n - abr + (a+nd)br^{n + 1} + dbr - dbr^{n + 1} \\
= ab - abr^n -ndbr^n-abr + abr^{n + 1} + ndbr^{n + 1}+ dbr - dbr^{n + 1} \\
= b(a - ar^n -ndr^n- ar + ar^{n + 1} + ndr^{n + 1}+ dr - dr^{n + 1}\\
= b(a - ar - ar^n + ar^{n + 1} - ndr^n + ndr^{n + 1} + dr - dr^{n + 1})\\
= b(a(1 - r) - ar^n(1 - r) - ndr^n(1 - r) + dr(1 - r^n))
\end{gather}\
$$
However I'm stuck here. I know that it is possible to factor out $(1 - r^n)$ into $(1-r)(\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}r^i)$ via the geometric series formula, but it will make the factoring even more difficult. That being said, the solution is very complicated and I did my factoring by hand, so there might be mistakes. Therefore, I would like to ask

if my expansion is wrong, and if it is what is the right expression
the factorization of the numerator expression, if possible.

Thanks for your help!
EDIT: if it helps, there is an additional condition on $r$, namely $r < 1$

oh, I forgot, but yes. I should also write that r < 1.

@ClaudeLeibovici oh, sadly no then.

What do you need the logarithm for? Most probably, there isn't a "better-looking" expression than just $\log$ with $S_n$ inside the brackets, as it is.

mostly for Project Euler problem 235. Now due the site's rules I can't share the solution so easily, but it essentially involves taking a log of everything because these polynomials can get very large.
